# Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server Communication link failure (0) state:"08S01" using Python SQLAlchemy 1.4.41

Tags: python, python-3.x, sql-server, sqlalchemy

We have a Dockerized FastAPI `fastapi==0.87.0`, `SQLAlchemy==1.4.41` OS: `Linux Ubuntu` which communicates to a remote MSSQL database OS:`Windows Server 2019` `Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-GDR) (KB5021127) - 14.0.2047.8 (X64)`

We have been using the following connection string for 2 years:

**Connection String**

```
DATABASE_URL = f"mssql+pyodbc://{config['username']}:{config['password']}@{config['SQLServerProduction']}/{config['db']}?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server&use_unicode=1&charset=utf8"
```

and suddenly today the following exception occurred:

**Python Error**

```
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Communication link failure (0)
```

From the same server another Dockerized Api in GO Lang also could not execute any operation relating to the same MSSQL database returning the following error:

**Go Error**

```
/app/site/site.go:192 read tcp **.**.**.**:*****->***.**.***.**:*****: read: connection reset by peer
```

From the same server another Dockerized machine have been running a python script and inserting data to the same MSSQL Database **without any exceptions using `pyodbc` library!**

**During the issue, the same database had been working properly in other operations.**

*Windows updated yesterday the following build:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/may-9-2023-kb5026362-os-build-17763-4377-b0133287-05dd-4bc5-
b1c3-5edaca650afd
but we don't think that is relative!*

**What we have already tried and didn't work:**

1. Check the Firewall and Router logs in order to see that the requests are resolved properly. *Everything resolves as expected*
2. Check in SQL Connection pool that a connection has been established. *A Connection has been established properly*
3. Check in SQL Profiler that the Insert Statement has been executed. *Query executed but never completed - With no Errors!*
4. Restart all Servers.
5. Rebuild all Dockers.
6. Change the Driver String to `ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server` and `SQL+Server`.
7. Check that ODBC Driver is properly installed in the remote MSSQL Database. *Version 2017.177.02.01*

**What we have tried and worked is installing `pymssql==2.2.7` library and change the Connection string to:**

```
DATABASE_URL = f"mssql+pymssql://{config['username']}:{config['password']}{config['SQLServerProduction']}/{config['db']}"
```

But we would be glad to know if you have any idea on finding a solution without using `pymssql==2.2.7` library?
And any idea on what may have caused this error.

Comment: So you've been through the 18,000+ files modified by KB5026362 and confirmed that not one of them has anything to do with this sudden impact to SQL Server? Have you considered just rolling it back?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning thank you very much for your comment. No we have not been through the 18000 files but we have read the affected files of the update and none of them were related to SQL. We will try a rollback in order to see if the update is the root of the problem.